# Change the prices of two or three products if they were added to the shopping cart together. Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Good afternoon!
Please help me implement this feature in woocommerce.
I have three specific products (with specific IDs 2, 3, 4).
I need to make sure that when adding two of them together to the cart, the prices for both of them change automatically. For example, for a product with id #2, the price was set to $ 100, and for a product with id #3, the price became$200.
Also, when they are all added together (three of them), the price changed for all three of them: product # 2 = 100; product # 3 = 200; product # 4 = 250.

I haven't found anything like this anywhere yet, so I would appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem on my own.
I made sure that the products I need "watch" each other in the basket. And if one of them "notices" the other, the price is updated for both of them.
In the same way, the price is updated if the three of them simultaneously "see" each other in the basket.
It may not be the best code, but it works and it works well.

The original code was taken from this resource and modified by me for my tasks.
(https://www.webroomtech.com/change-product-price-when-other-product-is-in-cart-woocommerce/)

```
function simple_func_product_in_cart($product_id){

    $product_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product_id );
    $in_cart = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_cart_id );
 
    if ( $in_cart ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'simple_change_price_of_product' );

function simple_change_price_of_product( $cart_object ) {   
    $target_product_id = 7101; // CHANGE THIS WITH YOUR PRODUCT ID
    if(simple_product_in_cart(7105)) {
    // Product is already in cart
        foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $key => $value ) {
            if ( $value['product_id'] == $target_product_id ) {
                $value['data']->set_price(160); // CHANGE THIS: set the new price
                $new_price = $value['data']->get_price();
            }
        }
    }
    
    $target_product_id = 7101; // CHANGE THIS WITH YOUR PRODUCT ID
    if(simple_product_in_cart(7107)) {
    // Product is already in cart
        foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $key => $value ) {
            if ( $value['product_id'] == $target_product_id ) {
                $value['data']->set_price(160); // CHANGE THIS: set the new price
                $new_price = $value['data']->get_price();
            }
        }
    }
    
    $target_product_id = 7105; // CHANGE THIS WITH YOUR PRODUCT ID
    if(simple_product_in_cart(7101)) {
    // Product is already in cart
        foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $key => $value ) {
            if ( $value['product_id'] == $target_product_id ) {
                $value['data']->set_price(170); // CHANGE THIS: set the new price
                $new_price = $value['data']->get_price();
            }
        }
    }
    
    $target_product_id = 7105; // CHANGE THIS WITH YOUR PRODUCT ID
    if(simple_product_in_cart(7107)) {
    // Product is already in cart
        foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $key => $value ) {
            if ( $value['product_id'] == $target_product_id ) {
                $value['data']->set_price(170); // CHANGE THIS: set the new price
                $new_price = $value['data']->get_price();
            }
        }
    }
    
    $target_product_id = 7107; // CHANGE THIS WITH YOUR PRODUCT ID
    if(simple_product_in_cart(7101)) {
    // Product is already in cart
        foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $key => $value ) {
            if ( $value['product_id'] == $target_product_id ) {
                $value['data']->set_price(180); // CHANGE THIS: set the new price
                $new_price = $value['data']->get_price();
            }
        }
    }
    
    $target_product_id = 7107; // CHANGE THIS WITH YOUR PRODUCT ID
    if(simple_product_in_cart(7105)) {
    // Product is already in cart
        foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $key => $value ) {
            if ( $value['product_id'] == $target_product_id ) {
                $value['data']->set_price(180); // CHANGE THIS: set the new price
                $new_price = $value['data']->get_price();
            }
        }
    }
}
```